# Unique instance ID required for Functional Mock-up Unit (FMU) Model

Tags: python, gcc, fmi

On Anaconda prompt, I am executing a Python source file having the following import statement:

```py
import pyfmi
```

Subsequently in the code, I am loading the model by the statements:

```py
self.modelname = "D:/path/model.fmu"

self.model = pyfmi.load_fmu(self.modelname, log_level=6)
```

Where `model.fmu` is my model.

My query is:

Is there any built-in parameter inside the model which serves as unique instance ID? I am asking this because I want to create more than one instances of the same FMU in the python file. The model, which is compiled using GCC compiler, should write a text file whose name should be unique for every instance. I want to derive the filename from the unique instance ID in the GCC model environment.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about the output from the model in terms of logging, then you can specify a specific log file name where an instance of the model should log information to.

I.e:

```
self.model = pyfmi.load_fmu(self.modelname, log_level=6, log_file_name="Instance1_log.txt")
```